# Where should I put the possessive apostrophe in the construction noun + "Proper Name" + possessed thing

Tags: grammar, possessives, apostrophe

The sentence is as follows:

> The association "Association Name" requirements.

Where should I put the possessive apostrophe?

> The association "Association Name"'s requirements.

OR

> The association's "Association Name" requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter where you put the apostrophe in that example it's going to look strange to some people—regardless of whether or not it's considered correct.

In this case, I think the apostrophe should go after the closing quotation mark—but the combination of those two punctuation marks (*"'s*) doesn't produce a clear presentation. And adding a space as you might for embedded quotes (*" 's*) doesn't work well for the possessive.

The best course is to rephrase the sentence itself in order to bypass the need for an apostrophe.

> The requirements *of* the association "Association Name" are . . .

Answer (score 0):

The possessive apostrophe comes with the immediate preceding noun. So here, the apostrophe would be added with the proper noun.

Viewing a similar but easier example:

> "This is my sister Jane's book." is correct
>   NOT
>   "This is my sister's Jane
>   book."

Comment: The commas are incorrect here. It indicates that your sister is Jane's book.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Removed now.